# Accidentally screwed up trash icon

Tags: trash, 18.04

While trying out the new Ubuntu 18.04 LTS I right-clicked on the trash desktop icon and clicked properties then changed the icon without thinking about the consequences.  Now I can't figure out how to get it back to the default. Please help.

Comment: I had this exact issue in ubuntu 16.04 but Erixhens answer helped

Answer (score 1):

I know I might be late but I just found the solution to this.
I read the solution on this site https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=42052.

Basicly you have to navigate to your /.config folder, open the nautilus folder and edit the metadata file. Delete everything after custom-icon= and then log out and log back in and your trash icon will be the same. 
If you edit the file and move the icon before logging out you will have to redo it.

Comment: Bro thanks a lot man. My default desktop icon has returned. I use 16.04LTS. I would like to know what to do in case i wanted to change the icon to say the one that looks like a basket. I should point out that i Tried changing but was basically using plain downloaded trash images so e.g when you download an image of a trash icon that's full, it still shows the filled up representation even after emptying the trash. So my question is how do i change the icon to a flexible one in that when i empty the trash, it shows that it is empty and vice versa. Thanks guys.